# display image from byteArray

Tags: android, arrays, image

I have a `Main` class with has `onCreate()` method. in that method i have made the MapFile class' object.and called its `readFile()` and `readIndex()` methods. in `readIndex()` method i call another class named `MapTile` where i read the images tiles from my binary file and there i have to display my image.

Question is, how can I display an image without putting my code into `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStare)` method? I am trying this way but on first line it gives me `NullPointerException`.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);           
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageTile, 0, imageTile.length);
image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your issue is not the byteArray but the `findViewById`. As you say that the NPE is on the first line. There are rules around this method you have two options to call it :

Either you use it to query a View you already have in the layout you called in `setContentView`
Or you use it on a View contained in a layout you inflated manually with a layout inflater

If you try to use it in your activity to call a View from any other layout than the one in `setContentView` that you have not inflated yourself, it will return null.

Comment: remove the line ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon); and replace it by ImageView image = new ImageView(this); and after setting the imageBitmap, add the ImageView to your layout

Answer (score 36):

adding a byte array to an android imageview:

```
        //byte[] chartData 
        ImageView imgViewer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chart_image);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(chartData, 0, chartData.length);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        imgViewer.setMinimumHeight(dm.heightPixels);
        imgViewer.setMinimumWidth(dm.widthPixels);
        imgViewer.setImageBitmap(bm);
```