# How to convert bitmap image to binary image in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I need to convert bitmap to binary image for my hw.Do u know anything about that?

Comment: Yes, I know something about that... (voted for close)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for an algorithm to perform the conversion?

The easiest way is to compare each pixel value with a fixed threshold: if the pixel value is less than the threshold, the corresponding output pixel is black (0), else it is white (1).

If you wish to determine the threshold automatically, you may want to implement Otsu's method. That method does a correct job overall when you can't make too many assumptions about the pixels distribution in your image.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_Method

As a reference, that's how it looks like in Mathematica:
`Binarize[image, threshold]`, and `Binarize[img]` for Otsu's method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bitmap convert function and write it to an output stream and then use the output stream to get for yourself the byte array
I hope that helps

Comment: start with giving more details about what you need. Your question does not make much sense.

Comment: I didnt get any idea of converting binary image

Answer (score 0):

you can look this link [converting Java bitmap to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array), it can convert bitmap to binary, can then you should look at  [display image from byteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520019/display-image-from-bytearray)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
Bitmap bitmapObtained =//get your bitmap
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapObtained.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

perhaps this is your code

```
imageID = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
              //  uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID);
                Log.v("dklfdlk",imageID);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageID);
if (bitmap != null) {
                    newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 78, 78, true);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    if (newBitmap != null) {
                        publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newBitmap));
}
```

try this