# Display image in ImageView from a binary array

Tags: android, imageview, binary-data

I have a web service to retrieve images which are converted to string and in my android app convert back to binary array. but unfortunately in stops with a force close error.
I'm using the code explained here to fill the imageView:
[display image from byteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520019/display-image-from-bytearray)

This is my web service method in C# which sends me the data:

```
public String GetPersonImage()
        {
            int PersonCode = 1;
            JPerson person = new JPerson(PersonCode);
            Image personImage = person.PersonImage;
            if (personImage == null)
                return "Nothing";
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                personImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

And this is how I'm trying to put my data in an ImageView:

```
            String pic = t.execute().get();
            byte[] picData = pic.getBytes();
            ImageView imgPerson = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPerson);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picData, 0, picData.length);
            imgPerson.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

the pic variable contains the data from web service. And this is my log cat:

```
11-13 14:08:23.092: D/dalvikvm(29229): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2290K, 41% free 8004K/13420K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
11-13 14:08:23.092: I/dalvikvm-heap(29229): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 185326656-byte allocation
11-13 14:08:23.143: D/dalvikvm(29229): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 41% free 7994K/13420K, paused 42ms, total 43ms
11-13 14:08:23.143: E/dalvikvm-heap(29229): Out of memory on a 185326656-byte allocation.
11-13 14:08:23.143: I/dalvikvm(29229): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
11-13 14:08:23.143: I/dalvikvm(29229):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a729a0 self=0x2a00bba8
11-13 14:08:23.143: I/dalvikvm(29229):   | sysTid=29229 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073849308
11-13 14:08:23.143: I/dalvikvm(29229):   | state=R schedstat=( 1210556247 2173314492 1073 ) utm=93 stm=28 core=0
11-13 14:08:23.143: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:428)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:446)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at com.example.shareholders.PersonnelInfo.clickHandler(PersonnelInfo.java:116)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-13 14:08:23.151: I/dalvikvm(29229):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 14:08:23.161: D/skia(29229): --- decoder->decode returned false
11-13 14:08:23.161: D/AndroidRuntime(29229): Shutting down VM
11-13 14:08:23.161: W/dalvikvm(29229): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    ... 11 more
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:428)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:446)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    at com.example.shareholders.PersonnelInfo.clickHandler(PersonnelInfo.java:116)
11-13 14:08:23.182: E/AndroidRuntime(29229):    ... 14 more
11-13 14:13:23.284: I/Process(29229): Sending signal. PID: 29229 SIG: 9
11-13 14:13:23.751: E/Trace(31566): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-13 14:13:23.791: I/METHOD INFO(31566): AppMenu.onCreate():21
11-13 14:13:23.912: D/dalvikvm(31566): GC_CONCURRENT freed 61K, 8% free 2752K/2964K, paused 15ms+11ms, total 77ms
11-13 14:13:24.051: D/gralloc_goldfish(31566): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: What size are the images more or less? It looks like the runtime is trying to allocate 185mb...

Comment: irrelevant to the question, but you are using an asynctask and calling get on it on the uitread. you are blocking the main thread exactly as if you were making your request on the ui thread. please don't do that and handle your server response in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: Read this [article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# server is sending you a base 64 string, and you're trying to read its bytes directly. You first need to decode it and then convert to a byte array.

Try this:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(pic, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes , 0, decodedBytes.length);
```

Comment: that would explain the 185Mb allocation. the base64 probably contains stuff that are interpreted as the size of the compressed image by the bitmapfactory.