# Android ListView with image and text using json

Tags: java, php, android, json, listview

I've been searching and searching for answers and tutorials but I can't find one. So here's my problem.. I am a newbie in android and web development. I want to create an android app for my website. I want to fetch image and text from my website using json and make it as a listview in android (See photo below). I know now how to create xml's for the android. The problem is what I will do in the java code and php code for the images and texts to be retrieve. I find some tutorials but they didn't really have the solutions because they all retrieve the image from the res/drawable. I want to retrieve mine from the server of my database like http//example.com/example.php Another thing is to make it clickable so when I click it, it will go to another xml/activity. I hope to find good tutorials for this.

[image: Image is as such]

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: @KamleshArya thanks but it the tutorial link is for populating listview with texts only.

Comment: @uhani_user create layout consisting of ImageView and TextView in it.anyway here is another link for more help http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: @KamleshArya i know how to make layout for the imageview and textview. The problem is the fetching code itself for the php and java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For manage your json you could create a [JsonAdapter](http://bebblebrox.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/android-json-adapter/), and for display remote image read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075637/loading-remote-images)

Or, if you send the image inside the json in some format (base64?) you have to handle it like bytearray [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520019/display-image-from-bytearray)

Comment: My problem here is that i want to retrieve the images for example in http://localhost/example/images.. in your tutorials i get how to retrieve the texts but not the images.. The tutorial for images are not exactly what i'm looking for. But thanks anyway. The links are informative :)

Comment: if your php service (http//example.com/example.php) accept in input an id that you use for extract a blob from your database you could use HTTP header for put out an image.

For example:
http//example.com/example.php?id=4

and then in PHP [create an output image](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php)

Comment: that i can see in all tutorials.. putting the specific HTTP header of the image in the java code. What if I have like 10 images to retrieve.. What header I will use?

Comment: you should make an HTTP call for each image at the url, and if you have a listview is quite simple:
each row call the getView method, anche in each row you have an image object that you could inflate myImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("http://example.com/example.php?id="+ currentLineId));

this solution is not secure, but it is the simplest.

For security you should create an AsynkTask that make an HTTP post with some user-key an then output the image like the link above:

'BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(**byteArrayReadFromAsynkTask**, 0, imageTile.length);'